# Give placeholder to select in Angular 6

Tags: angular, select, dropdown

I have a select option in which i want to give placeholder which says "select a category"

```
<form role="form" class="form form-horizontal" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #form="ngForm" ngNativeValidate>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-6 col-md-12">
                <fieldset class="form-group">
                    <label for="customSelect">Categories:</label>
                    <select class="custom-select d-block w-100" id="Category" [(ngModel)]="Category" name="Category" required>
                        <option value=" ">Select one category </option>                                     
                         <option *ngFor="let item of myBusinessList" [value]="item.id">{{item.name}}</option>
                    </select>
                </fieldset>                                
            </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-raised btn-danger">Save</button>
    </form>
```

If i remove [ngModel] then it works. If i write

```
<option value="undefined" selected>Select one category </option>
```

then it considers as one of the value. I have to make sure there is place and also it is required to select one of the value

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use `[value]="" selected hidden`

I have create a demo on **[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/give-placeholder-to-select-in-angular-6?file=src/app/app.component.html)**

```xml
<form role="form" class="form form-horizontal" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #form="ngForm" ngNativeValidate>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-6 col-md-12">
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <label for="customSelect">Categories:</label>
                <select class="custom-select d-block w-100" id="Category" [(ngModel)]="Category" name="Category" required placeholder="d.ff">
                    <option hidden [value]=""  selected>Select one category </option>
                    <option *ngFor="let item of myBusinessList" [value]="item.id">{{item.name}}</option>
                </select>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-raised btn-danger">Save</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I dont know how its working for you but its not working for me still

Comment: what you want do?

Comment: did you add css ?

Comment: What you have done in code is exactly how i want but its not working for me

Comment: Yes i added css

Comment: I have added only `[value]="" selected` and css. You can check Stackblitz link

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178501/discussion-between-ruchita-ajmera-and-krishna-rathore).

Comment: Could it be that `Category` is not initialized to an empty string in @RuchitaAjmera's code?

Comment: @ConnorsFan it worked like charm. It was not initialized that's why it was not working. Thanks!!

Answer (score 19):

If you want the first value to be selected when `Category` is still `undefined`, you can assign the value `undefined` to the first option with `ngValue`:

```
<option [ngValue]="undefined" hidden>Select one category</option>
```

Comment: I want that when drop down displays , user should know that they have to select category without it they should not proceed further.

Comment: The solution you gave will allow user to proceed further as it was treat undefined as value

Comment: @RuchitaAjmera - No. `Category` is already undefined. Having that value as an option does not change anything (except allowing the text to appear in the select box). It is up to you to decide what happens when the value is undefined.

Comment: It is allowing me to submit form with "select one category" option. But the scenario is user should one of the options then only he can submit.

Comment: Oh yes, you are right. The `required` attribute works when the value is an empty string, but not for `[ngValue]="undefined"`.

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks,
Why there are so many different ways to do one simple thing? I tried with all the permutation combinations that are defined out there. :|

Answer (score 7):

for a template driven angular form you may want to consider this [demo](https://angular-form-basic-template-driven-ljmjub.stackblitz.io).
you can find the code [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-basic-template-driven-ljmjub?file=app/app.component.ts)

for a simple html form here is a snippet.

```html
<form>
    <select required>
        <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Select a value</option>
        <option value="0">option 1</option>
        <option value="1">option 2</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

```
<option value="" disabled selected hidden>Select your option</option>
```

Comment: this is not the right way to make an option disable it will be still an option. as she is asking about a placeholder.

Comment: It works without [(ngModel)]="Category", not with it

Comment: With [(ngmodel)] you have not mentioned name tag, ngModel wont work without name tag. And if you mention name tag your code wont work like now.

Comment: my bad. i just made an update and it works as expected. Kindly check.

Answer (score 1):

simply use `[value]="undefined"`

```
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedCategory">
    <option [value]="undefined" disabled hidden>Select...</option>
    <option *ngFor="let c of categories">{{c}}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using **ngModel**, to be selected by default the **value** attribute of the option tag and the initial **category** value in the component class must be the same. And to make it hidden in the list you can use hidden attribute. For the consistency of validation issues the best way is to use **ngValue** instead of **value**.

in the component:

```
category: string = null;
```

in the template:

```
<option [ngValue]="null" hidden>Select one category </option>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. I've used the first option value as placeholder.

```xml
<div class="form-group">
     <label for="homeType">Example select</label>
     <select class="form-control" id="homeType" ngModel="1" name="homeType" required>
     <option  [disabled]="true" value="1" selected>{{ placeholder.select }}</option>
     <option value="house">House</option>
     <option value="flat">Flat</option>
     <option value="townHouse">Town House</option>
     </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out your code as given below, you have to add template variable to the code and assign it as the value then it will work.

```
<select class="custom-select d-block w-100" id="Category" [(ngModel)]="Category" name="Category" #category="ngModel" required>
                    <option value="category" disabled hidden>Select one category </option>                                     
                     <option *ngFor="let item of myBusinessList" [value]="item.id">{{item.name}}</option>
                </select>
```