# How to Set Placeholder on Select Tag in Angular 8?

Tags: angular, select, angular8

I am creating a dropdown to filter data so I have created a dropdown

```
<form  #filter="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="filterta(filter)" style="display: flex;">
       <select  ngModel #month="ngModel" name="month" required  >
                <option [ngValue]="null" [disabled]="true" >All</option>
                <option value="1">January</option>
       </select>
</form>
```

when i remove `ngModel #month="ngModel"`  these properties form select tag it shows placeholder option All and when i add these properties it shows Blank in Placeholder .

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Set initial value of `month = null` in the `component.ts` and add `[(ngModel)]="month"` in the `select` tag of `component.html`.

**component.ts**

`month = null`;

**component.html**

```
<form  #filter="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="filterta(filter)" style="display: flex;">
       <select name="month" [(ngModel)]="month" #month required>
                <option [ngValue]="null" [disabled]="true" >All</option>
                <option value="1">January</option>
       </select>
</form>
```

Comment: I had to do it for dynamic dropdowns scenario inside a for loop and setting to null was not feasible for me. I tried [ngValue]="undefined" [disabled]="true" and it worked in my case because the empty objects had undefined by default.

Comment: Instead of `[disabled]="true"` you can just use `disabled`

Answer (score 18):

This worked for me in Angular-10.

```
<select class="form-control" name="role" id="role" formControlName="role">
     <option value="" disabled selected>Select the role</option>
     <option *ngFor="let role of roleList" value="{{ role }}">{{role}}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try like this:

- Modify `ngModel #month="ngModel"` to `[(ngModel)]="selectedMonth" #month`
- In .ts file, add `selectedMonth = null;`

.ts

```
selectedMonth = null;
```

.html

```
<form  #filter="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="filterta(filter)" style="display: flex;">
       <select  [(ngModel)]="selectedMonth" #month name="month" required  >
                <option [ngValue]="null" [disabled]="true" >All</option>
                <option value="1">January</option>
       </select>
</form>
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-affdu9?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)**

Answer (score 3):

This works for me when model doesn't have initial value

```
<select [(ngModel)]="myModel">
        <option [ngValue]="undefined" [disabled]="true">Choose Type</option>
        <option *ngFor="let type of typeList; let i = index;" [value]="type.value">{{type.label}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: this solution worked after l searched for long

Answer (score 2):

You need to change your code a little bit

html file

```
[(ngModel)]="month" // This will set month value for select tag
```

in ts file

Set month value to deafult value whatever you want like

```
month = null;
```

Working code

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-plwvgg

Answer (score 2):

This works fine for me

```html
> <select [(ngModel)]="name">      
> <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Choose your number</option>   
> <option value="red">One</option>    
> <option value="green">Two</option>     
> <option value="black">Three</option> 
></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<select id="district" class="form-control">
  <!-- <option [disabled]="true">Select District/City</option> -->
  <option hidden value="" disabled selected>Select District/City</option>
  <option *ngFor="let postoffice of filterPostOffice" [value]="postoffice.District">
    {{ postoffice.District }}
  </option>
</select>
```

[Placeholder in Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51948197/give-placeholder-to-select-in-angular-6/51948269)

Comment: value attribute should be a blank string if you want to make a particular option to default option.
new FormControl(['']) 
`component.html`
value attribute should be a blank string eg: value=''"

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me:

```
<option value="" disabled selected>Text to display</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Angular, the option you want to act as a placeholder set the `value="undefined"` and place it on the very top as below:

```html
<select
  id="fmonthsCommitment"
  name="support"
  class="inp-si"
  (click)="commitmentNotification()"
  [(ngModel)]="commitmentInMonthsInput"
>
  <option value="undefined" disabled selected>
    Choose Months Commitment...
  </option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="12">12</option>
  <option value="24">24</option>
</select>
```